# Ruby on rails with ssl configuration not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, puma

I'm trying to connect rails server using puma with ssl.

The server is listening without ssl and everything is working fine using the server IP

but if I used ssl certificate with the following command:

```
RAILS_ENV=production puma -b 'ssl://0.0.0.0:8443?key=private.key&cert=cert.cert
```

it gives me always this error:

```
2019-06-19 17:54:15 +0000: SSL error, peer: INCOMING_IP, peer cert: , #<Puma::MiniSSL::SSLError: OpenSSL error: error:141F7065:SSL routines:final_key_share:no suitable key share - 337604709>
```

I'm using 
PUMA  Version 3.10.0
ruby 2.4.2-p198
Ubuntu 18.04

and all these configurations was on another server, 
I'm just trying to install a new server.

Thanks